# How to extract a number from a list on the web for google spreadsheet

Tags: html, list, xpath, import, google-sheets

I am trying to include a number in a google spreadsheet that is available from an API. The number is the value of btc respect to euro, and it can be found here:

```
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR
```

this is how what I download looks like:

```
{"error":[],"result":{"XXBTZEUR":{"a":["1470.98900","1","1.000"],"b":["1468.48300","2","2.000"],"c":["1470.99000","0.40659054"],"v":["13560.09485336","17663.32953039"],"p":["1464.65676","1450.02984"],"t":[28351,40087],"l":["1413.43300","1390.12500"],"h":["1489.88800","1489.88800"],"o":"1415.17300"}}}
```

The number is presented inside a list
The imports for google spreadsheets are
importxml, importhtml, importrange, importfeed, and importdata. But I could not get any of those to extract the number. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no in built function to handle a importing JSON. However, you can use the code provide [here](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a), so this exact purpose

Comment: thanks @JackBrown. Solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can import a number, for example `o:`, with:

```
=1*regexreplace(index(importdata("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR"),20),"[^\d|\.]","")
```